# flatten a nested list with indices in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list `['','','',['',[['a','b']['c']]],[[['a','b'],['c']]],[[['d']]]]`

I want to flatten the list with indices and the output should be as follows:

```
flat list=['','','','','a','b','c','a','b','c','d']
indices=[0,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5]
```

How to do this?

I have tried this:

```
def flat(nums):
    res = []
    index = []
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if isinstance(nums[i], list):
            res.extend(nums[i])
            index.extend([i]*len(nums[i]))
        else:
            res.append(nums[i])
            index.append(i)
    return res,index
```

But this doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I dont get the logic for your indicesm, can you please provide more infos?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @TobiasK The index should indicate the where the element belongs in the main list. For example d is the 5th element in main list so its index is 5. Similarly first 'a' belongs to 3rd element in main list so its index is 3.

Comment: @TobiasK make it as a 2d matrix and the row index will be the index required.

Comment: Important remark, if you don't know what's the maximum depth of your list you can't use any recursion based solution (converting to string is a recursion-based solution). This [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51649649/1720199) to understand why.

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

This implementation handles nested iterables with unbounded depth:

```py
def enumerate_items_from(iterable):
    cursor_stack = [iter(iterable)]
    item_index = -1
    while cursor_stack:
        sub_iterable = cursor_stack[-1]
        try:
            item = next(sub_iterable)
        except StopIteration:
            cursor_stack.pop()
            continue
        if len(cursor_stack) == 1:
            item_index += 1
        if not isinstance(item, str):
            try:
                cursor_stack.append(iter(item))
                continue
            except TypeError:
                pass
        yield item, item_index

def flat(iterable):
    return map(list, zip(*enumerate_items_from(a)))
```

Which can be used to produce the desired output:

```py
>>> nested = ['', '', '', ['', [['a', 'b'], ['c']]], [[['a', 'b'], ['c']]], [[['d']]]]
>>> flat_list, item_indexes = flat(nested)
>>> print(item_indexes)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
>>> print(flat_list)
['', '', '', '', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Note that you should probably put the index first to mimic what `enumerate` does. It would be easier to use for people that already know `enumerate`.

**Important remark** unless you are certain your lists will not be nested too much, you shouldn't use any recursion-based solution. Otherwise as soon as you'll have a nested list with depth greater than 1000, your code will crash. I explain this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51649649/1720199). Note that a simple call to `str(list)` will crash on a test case with `depth > 1000` (for some python implementations it's more than that, but it's always bounded). The typical exception you'll have when using recursion-based solutions is (this in short is due to how python call stack works):

```py
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded ...
```

### Implementation details

I'll go step by step, first we will flatten a list, then we will output both the flattened list and the depth of all items, and finally we will output both the list and the corresponding item indexes in the "main list".

#### Flattening list

That being said, this is actually quite interesting as the iterative solution is perfectly designed for that, you can take a simple (non-recursive) list flattening algorithm:

```py
def flatten(iterable):
    return list(items_from(iterable))

def items_from(iterable):
    cursor_stack = [iter(iterable)]
    while cursor_stack:
        sub_iterable = cursor_stack[-1]
        try:
            item = next(sub_iterable)
        except StopIteration:       # post-order
            cursor_stack.pop()
            continue
        if isinstance(item, list):  # pre-order
            cursor_stack.append(iter(item))
        else:
            yield item              # in-order
```

#### Computing depth

We can have access to the depth by looking at the stack size, `depth = len(cursor_stack) - 1`

```py
        else:
            yield item, len(cursor_stack) - 1      # in-order
```

This will return an iterative on pairs (item, depth), if we need to separate this result in two iterators we can use the `zip` function:

```py
>>> a = [1,  2,  3, [4 , [[5, 6], [7]]], [[[8, 9], [10]]], [[[11]]]]
>>> flatten(a)
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 1), (5, 3), (6, 3), (7, 3), (8, 3), (9, 3), (10, 3), (11, 3)]
>>> flat_list, depths = zip(*flatten(a))
>>> print(flat_list)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
>>> print(depths)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
```

We will now do something similar to have item indexes instead of the depth.

#### Computing item indexes

To instead compute item indexes (in the main list), you'll need to count the number of items you've seen so far, which can be done by adding 1 to an `item_index` every time we iterate over an item that is at depth 0 (when the stack size is equal to 1):

```py
def flatten(iterable):
    return list(items_from(iterable))

def items_from(iterable):
    cursor_stack = [iter(iterable)]
    item_index = -1
    while cursor_stack:
        sub_iterable = cursor_stack[-1]
        try:
            item = next(sub_iterable)
        except StopIteration:             # post-order
            cursor_stack.pop()
            continue
        if len(cursor_stack) == 1:        # If current item is in "main" list
            item_index += 1               
        if isinstance(item, list):        # pre-order
            cursor_stack.append(iter(item))
        else:
            yield item, item_index        # in-order
```

Similarly we will break pairs in two itératifs using ˋzip`, we will also use ˋmap` to transform both iterators to lists:

```py
>>> a = [1,  2,  3, [4 , [[5, 6], [7]]], [[[8, 9], [10]]], [[[11]]]]
>>> flat_list, item_indexes = map(list, zip(*flatten(a)))
>>> print(flat_list)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> print(item_indexes)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
```

#### improvement — Handling iterable inputs

Being able to take a broader palette of nested iterables as input could be desirable (especially if you build this for others to use). For example, the current implementation doesn't work as expected if we have nested iterables as input, for example:

```py
>>> a = iter([1, '2',  3, iter([4, [[5, 6], [7]]])])
>>> flat_list, item_indexes = map(list, zip(*flatten(a)))
>>> print(flat_list)
[1, '2', 3, <list_iterator object at 0x100f6a390>]
>>> print(item_indexes)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

If we want this to work we need to be a bit careful because strings are iterable but we want them to be considered as atomic items (not a as lists of characters). Instead of assuming the input is a list as we did before:

```py
        if isinstance(item, list):        # pre-order
            cursor_stack.append(iter(item))
        else:
            yield item, item_index        # in-order
```

We will not inspect the input type, instead we will try to use it as if it was an iterable and if it fails we will know that it’s not an iterable (duck typing):

```py
       if not isinstance(item, str):
            try:
                cursor_stack.append(iter(item))
                continue
            # item is not an iterable object:
            except TypeError:
                pass
        yield item, item_index
```

With this implementation, we have:

```py
>>> a = iter([1, 2,  3, iter([4, [[5, 6], [7]]])])
>>> flat_list, item_indexes = map(list, zip(*flatten(a)))
>>> print(flat_list)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> print(item_indexes)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

#### Building test cases

If you need to generate tests cases with large depths, you can use this piece of code:

```py
def build_deep_list(depth):
    """Returns a list of the form $l_{depth} = [depth-1, l_{depth-1}]$
    with $depth > 1$ and $l_0 = [0]$.
    """
    sub_list = [0]
    for d in range(1, depth):
        sub_list = [d, sub_list]
    return sub_list
```

You can use this to make sure my implementation doesn't crash when the depth is large:

```py
a = build_deep_list(1200)
flat_list, item_indexes = map(list, zip(*flatten(a)))
```

We can also check that we can't print such a list by using the `str` function:

```py
>>> a = build_deep_list(1200)
>>> str(a)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the repr of an object
```

Function `repr` is called by `str(list)` on every element from the input `list`.

#### Concluding remarks

In the end I agree that recursive implementations are way easier to read (as the call stack does half the hard work for us), but when implementing low level function like that I think it is a good investment to have a code that works in all cases (or at least all the cases you can think of). Especially when the solution is not that hard. That's also a way not to forget how to write non-recursive code working on tree-like structures (which may not happen a lot unless you are implementing data structures yourself, but that's a good exercise).

Note that everything I say “against” recursion is only true because python doesn't optimize call stack usage when facing recursion: [*Tail Recursion Elimination in Python*](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html). Whereas many compiled languages do [Tail Call recursion Optimization (TCO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization). Which means that even if you write the perfect [tail-recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion) function in python, it will crash on deeply nested lists.

If you need more details on the list flattening algorithm you can refer to the post I linked.

Comment: Why `elif item is not None:` rather than `else:`   ? Tia

Comment: This is unrelated to this question, just forgot to remove it from my code, `else:` is perfectly fine here. I'll edit that.

Comment: I would like to know more about your phrase "python doesn't optimize call stack usage when facing recursion" and what are the exact limitations python has in this regard?

Comment: The link that follows explain it, but basically, recursive function can be written in [_tail call_](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Tail_call) form. In some languages, if you write your recursive function this way, the compiler will automagically turn them into iterative code. In python there is no such thing and a recursive function will always remain recursive (no matter how well you write them). The problem with a recursive function is that until sub-calls return you (not you but your machine) will have to remember where the call came from (call stack). In python the call stack size is 1000.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and elegant solution:**

```
def flat(main_list):

    res = []
    index = []

    for main_index in range(len(main_list)):
        # Check if element is a String
        if isinstance(main_list[main_index], str):
            res.append(main_list[main_index])
            index.append(main_index)

        # Check if element is a List
        else:
            sub_list = str(main_list[main_index]).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(" ", '').replace("'", '').split(',')
            res += sub_list
            index += ([main_index] * len(sub_list))

    return res, index
```

Answer (score 0):

this does the job, but if you want it to be just returned then I'll enhance it for you

```
from pprint import pprint

ar = ["","","",["",[["a","b"],["c"]]],[[["a","b"],["c"]]],[[["d"]]]]
flat = []
indices= []

def squash(arr,indx=-1):
    for ind,item in enumerate(arr):
        if isinstance(item, list):
            squash(item,ind if indx==-1 else indx)
        else:
            flat.append(item)
            indices.append(ind if indx==-1 else indx)

squash(ar)

pprint(ar)
pprint(flat)
pprint(indices)
```

**EDIT**

and this is if you don't want to keep the lists in memory and return them

```
from pprint import pprint

ar = ["","","",["",[["a","b"],["c"]]],[[["a","b"],["c"]]],[[["d"]]]]

def squash(arr,indx=-1,fl=[],indc=[]):
    for ind,item in enumerate(arr):
        if isinstance(item, list):
            fl,indc = squash(item,ind if indx==-1 else indx, fl, indc)
        else:
            fl.append(item)
            indc.append(ind if indx==-1 else indx)
    return fl,indc

flat,indices = squash(ar)

pprint(ar)
pprint(flat)
pprint(indices)
```

I'm not expecting you would need more than 1k recursion depth which is the default setting

Comment: Recursive solution can be dangerous for extreme cases

Comment: @OmkarDeshpande please enlighten me of an actual scenario aside from implementation possible mistakes

Comment: I think @cglacet answer has covered all "scenario". :)

Comment: @OmkarDeshpande I don't see any problem other than the depth limit and difficulty in debugging which cglacet referenced. Recursion is mostly avoided because of those parts in addition to the complexity of the logic "sometimes". If there is a major issue with using recursion, please be more specific so we could learn from it.

Comment: These two problems by themselves are good reasons to favor iteratives solutions. On the other hand reasoning about recursive solution is often easier, there is a tradeoff in that choice. Either you favor code readability/maintainability and you should opt for a recursive solution, or you favor safety/applicability and you should use an iterative solution. In cases where your problem is a low-level one like here, I would tend to recommend the iterative solution for 2 reasons: (i) you won't maintain this often, (ii) you want it to be safe and to work in the broader range of cases.

Comment: If you make an informed decision, both solutions are perfectly fine, you just need to know what your implementation offers and what it doesn't. For example if you have a recursive version, you should provide a docstring that states explicitly that your function doesn't work on deeply nested lists.